# Adding multiple views to RelativeLayout with loop

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to add multiple views to RelativeLayout that I declared inside xml. Looping is the only way because I do not know how many elements needed to add there, since the size is dynamic. But I got this error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Code:

```
View inf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_table_edit, null);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamss = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
for (int i = 0; i < putzones.size(); i++) {
        inf.setX((float) putzones.get(i).getPosX());
        inf.setY((float) putzones.get(i).getPosY());
        addMap.addView(inf, layoutParamss);
}
```

What is wrong here, since when I'm trying to add views by clicking items it works with the same code, without any error. code is same when I am adding by clicking item without loop. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `addMap.removeView()` call this function above `addMap.addView(inf, layoutParamss);`

Comment: move the View inf reference  inside the loop.

Comment: @HardikVasani This doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: @ChandraSharma is right, after the first loop, inf has been added to a parent, android throws error when u add the same child to another view. Just move the declaration of inf into the loop, it will create a new child for each loop

Comment: @HardikVasani I have tried it. Not helping.

Comment: @ChandraSharma I'll try it now, and get back to you

Comment: @hjchin I should add same view to the layout

Comment: same view but different view id. you inflate it from the same xml but they are not the same instance.

Comment: @ChandraSharma wow, thanks it helped <3

Comment: @ChandraSharma add it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new instance of item_table_edit at each loop's iteration.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamss = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
for (int i = 0; i < putzones.size(); i++) {
        View inf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_table_edit, null);
        inf.setX((float) putzones.get(i).getPosX());
        inf.setY((float) putzones.get(i).getPosY());
        addMap.addView(inf, layoutParamss);
}
```